# IntelliJ refusing to add custom component

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

my problem is as follows: Assume that we have the following file:

```java
package p;
import javax.swing.*;
public class test extends JPanel {
  test(){
    super(true);
  }
}
```

I save the file and compile it. Now, in IntelliJ, I open a form and try to add `test` to it. It won't work! I click 'Non-Palette Component', click on my form and in the dialog that open up, I type `p.test` as my class name (IntelliJ even offers name completion here) and check 'create binding automatically'. After I click ok, nothing happens. But - if I take 'javax.swing.JButton' for the class name, it works. It's ridiculous. I don't see what I am doing wrong? Does test have to implement or override a certain function? Do I have to modify a path? Or should I just kick my PC out of my window?

Comment: +1, since so solid reason given for the downvote, and to me the question looks authentic and genuine.

Comment: As an aside, `super(true)` is superfluous. Does IntelliJ require a no-arg constructor for custom components?

Comment: Had you tried overriding [getPrefferedSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()), and let it return some Dimension object like `return new Dimension(300, 300);`, might be your test class is added, though some layouts, will tend to return `0,0` as the size of the `JPanel`, if the size is not provided. Try to do this, might be it will work.

Comment: First of all - thanks for your comments and @GagandeepBali: Thanks for the upvote!
I tried your idea but IntelliJ still doesn't display my 'test'-class. Interesting enough, it is not even added to the controls-hierarchy, where all the controls of a form are displayed.

Comment: @trashgod: Using a no-arg-constructor makes it easier as I do not have to provide the custom initialization. But I borrowed the idea of an arg-constructor to force IntelliJ to ask me for custom initialization. Sadly, it does not even do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Test : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

The problem is that you have the project language level set to 1.7 and using JDK 1.7 to build it. IntelliJ IDEA is running under JDK 1.6 on your system and cannot load the custom component class that was compiled with the 1.7 language level.

Possible solutions to this problem:

- change project/module JDK to 1.6
- in IDEA 12 it's possible to [configure bytecode version per module](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/2950/20130122131649.png), set it to 1.6
- in **Additional command line parameters** field specify the following options: `-source 1.6 -target 1.6`
- [run IDEA under JDK 1.7](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/08/running-mustang/) (applies to Windows and Linux, not recommended on Mac)

Comment: Well, that's it. I am somewhat upset to see that IntelliJ does not run from 1.7 yet. Anyway, thanks for that detailed and helpful answer!

Comment: To change the runtime on actual Intellij Installations: [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under?page=6)

Answer (score 3):

Are you running the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA? The action you describe works for me in 11.1.5 and 12.0.2 (the latest versions for IDEA 11 and 12). There might be a bug in an earlier version. Also, since `test` is a 'JPanel', are you selecting the "Is Container" option on the "Add Non=Palette Component". For the simple example you show, without this option selected, I do not get anything *visible* in the GUI designer when it is not selected in the "UI Designer" tool window. But you mentioned you do not even see it in the controls-hierarchy.

If you are at the latest version, I recommend you check the log (*Help > Reveal Log*) to see if there is an error in there that might shed some light on the issue.

Lastly, you can try invalidating the caches and restarting. (*File > Invalidate Caches*). It's possible there is some corruption that is causing an issue.

*I would have added this as a comment to your question, but I do not have enough reputation points to do such.*

Comment: I invalidated the caches without success. :(

Comment: The idea with the log was a good one - but it doesn't help me. Maybe you can tell me, what's going on:
The log says:
blah blah..
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Test : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
blah blah..
[  89423]  ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Last Action: EditorEscape

My JDK is 1.6.0_31. I'll try upgrading it and tell you whether it worked or not. Apart from that, I don't know what causes that error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compile the custom component and then click on `Reload Custom Components` button on the toolbar. That solved the issue for me.